# how to to receive list of objects in magento2 api method?

Tags: magento2, api

need to pass following object:

```
{  
   "category_code":"43",
   "attribute_filters":[  
      {  
         "price":{  
            "lte":20
         }
      },
      {  
         "vintage":{  
            "eq":"blue"
         }
      },
      {  
         "size":{  
            "in":[  
               "medium",
               "large"
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "attribute_include":[  
      "type",
      "color",
      "size",
      "sku"
   ]
}'
```

to custom API method:

```
 * @api
 *
 * @param int $category_code
 * @param string[] $attribute_filters
 * @param string[] $attribute_include
 *
 *
 * @return string JSON encoded objects data
 */

public function myMethod($category_code, $attribute_filters, $attribute_include);
```

But in result r receive following exception:

`{"message":"Notice: Array to string conversion in ... TypeProcessor.php ...}`

It is required to keep object in this format, as this is presented by specifications, how should i properly set the doctypes vars for this API to receive data ?

**UPD**

tried to  make

`@param \Magento\Framework\DataObject[] $attribute_filters`

but it throws :

`{"message":"Property \"Price\" does not have corresponding setter in class \"Magento\\Framework\\DataObject\"...}`

Seems like it doesnt recognize magic setters and getter via ReflectionClass

Comment: Did you get some solution @Anonymous ..Facing the same problem

Comment: yes, I did, but i had to slightly change the input format, will post my answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's no other option than change format to following:

```
  "attribute_filters" : 
  [  
    {
      "attribute" : price",
      "condition" : {  
        "lte":20
       }
    }
  ],
```

Then, I registered simple custom storage custom model `AttributeFilter` with getters and setters:

```
<?php

class AttributeFilter
{

  public $attribute;
  public $condition;

  /**
   * Set attribute code
   *
   * @param $attr
   */
  public function setAttribute($attr)
  {

      $this->attribute = $attr;
  }

  /**
   * Get attribute code
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getAttribute()
  {

      return $this->condition;
  }

  /**
   * Set
   *
   * @param $condition
   */
  public function setCondition($condition)
  {
      $this->condition = $condition;
  }

  /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getCondition()
  {
      return $this->condition;
  }


}
```

and then, declared in api interface:

```
* @param \My\Module\Model\AttributeFilter[] $attribute_filters
```